# Selecting the last day price by using LAG() function

Tags: postgresql

I have a user transaction table which is having a userid, date, itemid, price and prev_day_price column.
Sample is:

| userid | date | itemid | price | prev_day_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-24 | archicad | 1200.0 |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-23 | archicad | 1240.0 |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-23 | archicad | 1240.0 |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-21 | archicad | 1100.0 |  |

I need to find the previous (last) day price for each item. I'd like to apply the lag function but also a group by so I can find the previous price by userid and itemid. As my table some days having a more than one rows\price by item and it doesnt goes on 24-12-2020 - 25-12-2020 - 26-12-2020.

| userid | date | itemid | price | prev_day_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 |  |

Now, its starts to confusing and melting my mind to using lag function. Before the update prev_day_price column i'd tried to see preview results by lag function:

```
SELECT*,
  lag(price) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid, date, userid) AS prev_day_price 
FROM userlog
```

But result is:

| userid | date | itemid | price | prev_day_price | prev_day_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-21 | archicad | 1100.0 |  |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-24 | archicad | 1200.0 |  |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-24 | archicad | 1200.0 |  | 1200.0 |
| 1 | 2020-12-24 | archicad | 1200.0 |  | 1200.0 |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 |  |  |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 |  | 1400.0 |

It sems my query doesnt work properly. I think so i missed something important. My expected result like:

| userid | date | itemid | price | prev_day_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 | 1200 |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 | archicad | 1400.0 | 1200 |
| 1 | 2020-12-24 | archicad | 1200.0 | 1240 |
| 1 | 2020-12-23 | archicad | 1240.0 | 1100 |
| 1 | 2020-12-23 | archicad | 1240.0 | 1100 |
| 1 | 2020-12-21 | archicad | 1100.0 | 1100 |

I tried with lag(price,1) instead of lag(price) to offset by 0 and set default to 0 but it does not work either. The output format is not too important as long as I can get it into an array in the end. I'm using Postgres. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why doesn't your solution work properly?**

`lag()`, as well as every other window function, work on the window you are defining. In your case you define a partitioned window, a group, so to speak. The `lag()` function is executed only within this group, not over the groups. So, it returns the previous values **within** the partition. E.g. for the `2020-12-26` it return `NULL` for the first record (as there is no previous record before the first one) and the value for the first record in the second one. But this happens **separately** within every `date` group. This explains your result.

---

Solution for **Postgres 11+** :

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2001a63238eea40474b8616aa5a702fc)

```
SELECT
    *,
    first_value(price) OVER (
        ORDER BY itemid, userid, mydate 
        GROUPS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS prev_day_price 
FROM userlog
```

You have to define another window, on which you can act. Instead of windowing all dates separately, it is a great idea to bundle all records from the current and the previous date group. This is exactly what the `GROUPS` window was made for. Withing this group you can order your records by date and take the first value. This is exactly what you expect.

---

Solution for **Postgres versions <11** :

(Neither `GROUPS` windows nor `PRECEDING != UNBOUNDED` are supported)

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a63fa4a9771518189aa16a786e7e1cab)

```
SELECT
    u.itemid,
    u.mydate,
    u.userid,
    s.price                                          -- 5
FROM userlog u
JOIN (                                               -- 4
    SELECT
        itemid, mydate, userid,
        COALESCE(                                    -- 3
             lag(price) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid, userid ORDER BY mydate),  -- 2
             price
        ) as price
    FROM (
        SELECT
            itemid, mydate, userid,
            MAX(price) as price                      -- 1
        FROM userlog
        GROUP BY itemid, mydate, userid
    ) s
) s USING (itemid, mydate, userid)
```

1. Reduce all groups to one single records, e.g. with group and aggregate. Another opportunity could be using `SELECT DISTINCT ON (itemid, mydate, userid)`
2. Shift the previous `price` within each group (well, only the `itemid`/`userid` groups, the `mydate` column must be only used for ordering!) using the `lag()` function
3. Because the first record has no previous one, the current will be taken. This is what the `COALESCE()` function does.
4. Join this result to your original table and...
5. ... return the "lagged" `price` from it.

Comment: Sorry for my late response to your quite perfect answer. Been little busy at work. Yes, thats what i want. I just need a couple of changes for using in update the cells. I will try to do that with UPDATE operator.